# How to remove 'nullness annotation is redundant' warning when using @NonNullByDefault and arrays? (Eclipse, NullAnnotation)

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, annotations, nullable

I get the error

```
Null type safety (type annotations): The expression of type 'String' needs unchecked conversion to conform to '@NonNull String'
```

at statement A of this class:

```
package org.abego.util;

public class MyClass {
    private String[] names = new String[]{"Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"};

    public String getName(int index) {
        String name = names[index];
        return name; /* statement A */
    }
}
```

The package `org.abego.util` defines the default nullness to be "@NonNull":

```
@org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault
package org.abego.util;
```

When adding `@NonNull` to the array definition:

```
package org.abego.util;

import org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull;

public class MyClass {
    private @NonNull String[] names = new @NonNull String[]{"Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"};

    public String getName(int index) {
        String name = names[index];
        return name; /* statement A */
    }
}
```

the warning at statement A goes away, however I get a new warning

```
The nullness annotation is redundant with a default that applies to this location
```

for the type `@NonNull String[]` in the array definition.

I found no way to make this code warning-free.

Could the 'redundant' warning be wrong? It is my understanding the `NonNullByDefault` declaration will make sure a type definition `String[]` will be interpreted as `String @NonNull[]`, but not as `@NonNull String[]` or as `@NonNull String @NonNull[]`. So the explicit nullness annotation in `@NonNull String[]` is not redundant, but necessary to get the effective type `@NonNull String @NonNull[]`.

(I am using Eclipse 4.5 (Mars) and jdk1.8.0_60.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectations are correct. `@NonNullBeDefault` doesn't affect any details of an array type (unless you include [DefaultLocation.ARRAY_CONTENTS](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/annotation/DefaultLocation.html#ARRAY_CONTENTS) in the annotation's [value](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/annotation/NonNullByDefault.html#value--)).

I believe this to be a variant of https://bugs.eclipse.org/440398

Thanks for the concise example, btw.

Comment: I agree the bug originally reported in https://bugs.eclipse.org/440398 and "my" bug are most likely related. But one should definitely add both code examples to the test suite for this bug as the different "default" handling may make a difference.

Comment: Sure, I already copied a variant of your example to the bug, to be added as a regression test.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: I am currently making a large code base "nullable-clean". Most of the remaining warnings seem to be related a bug already reported on stack overflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32617682/eclipse-external-null-annotation-for-java-lang-objectgetclass). Could you have a look? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the other question - I answered there.

Comment: As I have not enough reputation points to comment on "the other question": similar to getClass() also the expression `SomeType.class` should be considered to always be non-null.

Comment: Class literals (`SomeType.class`) are already detected as non-null, as per https://bugs.eclipse.org/382789 fixed since Eclipse 4.3. LMK if you observe differently.

Comment: We already have a patch under review which fixes the problem in this question, it's in https://bugs.eclipse.org/467094

Comment: Not sure if my class literal [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32642992/3900879) is the same as Udo's, but I would appreciate it if you could take a look, Stephan.