# Eclipse null analysis issues null type safety warning for class literal

Tags: java, eclipse, null, annotations, eclipse-jdt

Consider the following partial content of an Eclipse project that has null analysis enabled:

*Eclipse Mars Release (4.5.0; 20150621-1200) for Windows 64-bit*
*Oracle JDK 1.8.0_60*

**package-info.java**

```
@org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNullByDefault
package bar;
```

**Foo.java**

```
package bar;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}

class Base<T> {
    private final Class<T> type;

    public Base(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Class<T> getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base<String> {
    public Derived() {
        super(String.class); // <-- Null type safety warning here
    }
}
```

Null analysis produces the following warning in the call to the superclass ctor in `Derived`:

```
Null type safety (type annotations): The expression of type 'Class<String>' needs unchecked conversion to conform to '@NonNull Class<@NonNull String>'
```

What is the correct way to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conflict you are seeing is between the type arguments ...

- ... of the required type: `@NonNull String`
- ... of the provided type: `String`

The non-null type argument comes into the picture from `extends Base<String>`, which under the regime of `@NonNullByDefault` is expanded to `extends Base<@NonNull String>`. From here it percolates all the way up to the super constructor, to render its signature after type argument substitution as `(@NonNull Class<@NonNull String>)`. By contrast, the class literal is seen by the compiler as having type `@NonNull Class<String>`, which is not compatible.

The real solution will come via [Bug 477719](https://bugs.eclipse.org/477719), see in particular the discussion in comment 3 f.

For the time being (with Eclipse Mars) you may have to reduce the effect of `@NonNullByDefault` so that `@NonNull Class<String>` will be accepted. This can be achieved by a more specific @NNBD declaration on top of class `Derived` like this

```
import static org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.DefaultLocation.*;
...
@NonNullByDefault({PARAMETER, RETURN_TYPE, FIELD, TYPE_BOUND})
class Derived extends Base<String> {
...
```

Here we are leveraging the fact, the @NNBD can be fine tuned regarding the locations to which it applies. In this declaration the difference to an argument-less `@NonNullByDefault` lies in omitting the location `TYPE_ARGUMENT`, which means that `String` in `extends Base<String>` will no longer be affected like mentioned above. Ergo the super constructor will now have this signature: `(@NonNull Class<String>)` and all compiles without warnings.

By putting the fine tuned @NNBD on the class `Derived` the scope of this workaround is kept a small as possible.

Comment: Thanks, Stephan.  Apologies for not going back and reviewing [Bug 477719](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=477719) before creating this question.  Otherwise I would have seen the additional discussion between you and Udo that occurred subsequent to you creating the bug after answering my previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32617682/3900879).  With that information, I would have been able to infer your workaround and saved you some time. :-)

Comment: n.p. -  May the answer also help others in the future :)

Comment: The “fix” to 477719, to assume that `T.class` is of type `Class<@NonNull T>` is kind of odd. It causes obviously wrong statements like `@NonNull String s = String.class.cast(null);` to pass without a warning. Or generally, it seems to assume that any method taking a `Class<X>` and returning an `X` to return a non-null value.

Comment: As long as the system libraries are not null-annotated, working with generic library classes is inevitably a bumpy road. Please see the javadoc of `Class.cast()`: "_@return the object after casting, or null if obj is null_". Ergo, that method should have signature `@Nullable T cast(@Nullable Object)`, and the compiler would correctly analyze your snippet. Fortunately, external annotations let you do exactly that. I agree that the choice to hard-code that type argument as nonnull is a bit arbitrary, but back then we had good reasons I believe. It is not possible to pass this option to the user.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann I just found out that the project where I stumbled over this had another issue: it doesn’t work when the custom annotations have `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)`, even when all involved classes are there in source code. I can live with it, but think, Eclipse should issue a warning about the unsupported `@Retention`.